# jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I'm hitting my head on the wall against this one ...

I have the following code:

```
$("#home").click(function(e) {
    $(".tabs").attr("src","tabs-home.gif");
    $(".islice").hide('fast');
    $(".islice").load("home.html");
    $(".islice").show('fast');  
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works perfectly fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but IE only runs attr() and does not do either the hide/show or the load. I tried removing the hide and show and it still does not work.

IE reports no syntax errors, even with DebugBar. What could I be doing wrong?

You can see the live site at  http://www.brick-n-mortar.com

Comment: I have the same issue. And NOTHING works, I have tried ALL of the suggested solutions below. :(  I am stuck and give up.

Comment: Another try would be setting DOM's `innerHTML` after loading the content with `$.ajax()` as an alternative.

Answer (score 48):

Many sites I have found have suggested that IE may be caching your code and suggest to append the code to

```
$("#home").click(function(e) {
    $(".tabs").attr("src","tabs-home.gif");
    $(".islice").hide('fast');
    $(".islice").load("home.html?" + new Date().getTime() );
    $(".islice").show('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This should ensure that a IE isn't caching.

See http://zacster.blogspot.com/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html for more info.

Comment: It'd be better to append a timestap, so
`$('.islice').load('home.html' + new Date().getTime());`

Comment: S.Kiers and EMMERICH: You saved my life. I was trying to figure out why the **** IE was not loading my initial start-page with the back-button of the browser (I do some AJAX-Loading with Hash-tags) and every other site would work as excepted. Adding the Random (or better the Timestamp) worked out :DDD

Comment: any chance, if this is the answer, you could mark it as such? I'd appreciate it...

Comment: should it be $(".islice").load("home.html?" + new Date().getTime() ); instead? I mean, missing the '?' following home.html

Answer (score 16):

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

This will clear cache in IE and .load() will work. I've tried it.

Answer (score 13):

If the HTML that you are loading is broken, jQuery's .load() will not work in IE..
It was the problem for me. After I fixed the HTML , everything worked great in IE also !

Comment: My URL loads fine in IE directly, but the $('#id').html(data) wont display anything.  Alas no errors either.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem and was scratching my head all day long. However finally found a work around and realized what a weirdo IE is.

First of all,

```
$(".islice").load("home.html");
```

won't work no matter how hard we try. We will instead have to use

```
$.get("home.html", function (data) ....... );
```

I will explain the "....." because a usual

```
$.get("home.html", function (data) { $(".islice").html(data); }); // doesn't work
```

won't work.

Instead

```
$.get("home.html", function (data) { 
    data = '"' + data + '"';    
    $(".islice").html(data);
    var newHTML = $('.islice').html();
    $('.islice').html(newHTML.substr(1,newHTML.length-2));
}); // works
```

will work.

Explanation: => data may have new line chars. so setting innerHTML = data; breaks because of them. By adding quotes we convert it into a string but making that html adds extra quotes so I get rid of the quotes again.

Moral: => IE sucks.. Nothing else..

Answer (score 4):

I found the .load() function did not work very well with IE, but using $.get() instead worked perfectly, e.g.

```
var dummy = new Date().getTime();
$.get("home.html" + dummy, function(data) {
   $(".islice").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Tried this and it is useful to confirm that the fetch is working.
Alas the .html(data) line silently does nothing.

Comment: I think you forgot the question mark here.
`$.get("home.html?" + dummy, function(data) {`...

Answer (score 4):

I found this workaround to be working:

```
$.ajax("loaded.html", {
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#content-1").html(data);
    },
    dataType:"html"
});
```

where:

- "loaded.html" is the URL to the file to load.
- $("#content-1") is the element that will contain the loaded data (and scripts).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with IE9.

All ajax requests die silently by default. By using http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ I was able to determine the type of error by logging the exception message: An error with the code **c00ce56e**.

It turns out that this means the response is not being passed **utf-8 encoded**, as it should be in response to an ajax request.

Turns out I had an typing error in `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem occurred because the ambiguous encoding. Try to specify the response encoding explicitly (that is, the charset in the HTTP Header), something like:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys... I had same problem with ie 8 and older. This is my solution, hope it helps somebody:

1) At first it's pretty hard to debugging ajax in IE. Why? Console is not upto the mark, but there is another bigger problem - caching. First time you load something wrong it stays in cache. Than you spend 2 hours fixing problem seeing same result (when you do this 1st time). Thanks to this article (and discusion): http://zacster.blogspot.cz/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html I customized my ajax calls like this:

$(container).load(link +'?random=' +  Math.random()*99999 +  ' .post-list li', function() {
  // do some stuff
}

Random URL works great

2) @Neno is right! IE have problems with mistakes in HTML. Validate your loading HTML http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I was stuck with IE loading an ajax call.  It turned out I had a left over </div> tag which caused the html to not validate.  Adding the math.random to the url took care of the IE caching.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The `e.preventDefault()` won't make any difference in IE - you'll have to use `return false;` to stop things from happening:

```
$("#home").click(function(e) {
    $(".tabs").attr("src","tabs-home.gif");
    $(".islice").hide('fast');
    $(".islice").load("home.html");
    $(".islice").show('fast');  
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

To debug this in detail, take a look at [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).

Comment: -1 jQuery extends the event object to make e.preventDefault(); be cross browser.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29: Prevents the browser from executing the default action. Use the method isDefaultPrevented to know whether this method was ever called (on that event object). Fixed where necessary (IE).

Comment: I did not know that they had updated it to work with IE as well - it didn't last time I checked. However, adding return false; should still solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent having IE bugging on that, add a math.random() parameter to it so it doesn't use this unrelevant cache...

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and was able to make it work this way:

`.load()` and `.html()` don't work very well in IE; especially if you don't have valid HTML.

```
$("#home").click(function(e) {
    $(".tabs").attr("src","tabs-home.gif");
    $(".islice").hide('fast');
    $.ajax({
        url: "home.html",
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $(".islice")[0].innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
    $(".islice").show('fast');  
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `.load()`ing into a `<table>`?

Hmm... Maybe push the `.islice` class up a level, into the `<td>`, or maybe a `<div>` in between...

(Not that that's necessarily the issue, but it's a possiblity...)

Comment: That depends entirely on what he's returning from serverside. If the result is just a collection of table rows, without the wrapping <table> tag, it will work just fine the way it is.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: I had checked before I responded; he's sending back divs, or full tables.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: infact, I had even checked with the script debugger: the content was getting added inside the table tag, but it wasn't getting rendered to screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, for me work add in head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

Answer (score -4):

If load is with PHP, reset your array values. For example:

```
$result = ''; // do this
$row = ''; // do this
$data = ''; // IMPORTANT Kills odd behavior CACHE FOR IE

$result = mysql_query("your sql here");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){          
$data[] = $row ..... blah blah blah...
```

Comment: PHP doesn't maintain state (unless you directly access $_SESSION or some other session data store), and even if it did it would have no effect on IE, as IE isn't privy to the PHP code on the server.