# Jquery load not working on internet explorer after then ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In firefox or chrome or other browsers i dont have this problem but in ie not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divplayer').load("/player/index.php");
    $("a.eklebeni").live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.png', this).attr('src', 'img/eklendi.png');
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
        $('#divplayer').html('<img src="img/player.png" class="png" alt="" />');
        $('#divplayer').load("/player/index.php");
        });
});
```

I dont know why but load function not working ?

Thanks

Comment: **Why not? What happens?** What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Look at the JavaSript console and see if there are any reported errors, then post the errors. And whatever line of script/html might be implicated.

Comment: Perhaps the answer lies in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/ ?

Comment: All versions of IE. And javascript console not showing error this is facebook iframe application. You can look at apps.facebook.com/muzikarsivi   . but player load script not working

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these a jQuery related solutions... but they're both things you should be aware of in the difference between IE and W3C (everyone else).  It looks like you might have coded for the latter which is why in IE it's not working as you expect, but without knowing what's not working this is a big of a WAG.

In IE, `window.event` gives you access to the event (not the first argument passed to the event handling code) so your function should be:

```
//...
.live('click',function(event) {
  event=event||window.event;
//...
```

To prevent an event in W3C you should use `event.preventDefault()`, in IE you need to set `event.returnValue=false` in order to prevent the default event.  Which means changing a change to `event.preventDefault()`:

```
if (event.preventDefault) {event.preventDefault():}
else {event.returnValue=false;}
```

Comment: You don't have to do this with jQuery, it normalizes the `event` object (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). It is always passed to the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a million times with IE caching the content, which doesn't help because there will be no errors or problems reported, it just won't work. Try something like this and see what happens:

```
$('#divplayer').load("/player/index.php?timestamp=" + (+new Date));
```