# .load() does not work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, load

I am trying to have a little dynamics work in this website http://peps.sqps.nl 
Everything seems to work well untill I test the website in IE, it just doesnt give any content back.

The js I use is as following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li.navItem a').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $('article').load(url + ' article', function(){
        $('article').fadeTo(1200, 1);
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

the html of the dynamic part is as following, where the `<article></article>` part is supposed to act dynamicly.

```
<section id="content">
  <div id="article">
    <article>
         content is in here
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

The solution given here on similar problems didnt fix the bug
Anyone has any ideas?

Thnx!

Comment: That URL looks a bit weird with the `+ ' article'`

Comment: @Phil - That's part of the jQuery `.load` method. It specifies a fragment of the loaded document to use, rather than the whole document. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JamesAllardice ah yes, now I remember, but shouldn't it be ` #article`?

Comment: Problem is that IE won't accept XML "fragments" as valid DOM elements. It probably has sort of "white list" of all valid tags, and you can't treat any other tag as DOM element - jQuery won't help either. Just change the logic and load the contents into ordinary `<div>` instead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that was indeed the problem :) its fixxed now. Thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL looks like it would be badly formed.

```
url = "http://site.com/path/to/page"
load_url = url + ' article'
alert(load_url); // Displays "http://site.com/path/to/page article"
```

Is this what you really want?

Comment: I think that probably is what the OP wants. The jQuery `.load` method allows you to specify a selector to load a fragment of a page, rather than the whole document. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: As @JamesAlladice mentions above, he could be attempting to load a page fragment but it should be `#article`, not just `article`.

Comment: The bit after the space can be any jQuery selector, so 'article' is fine actually. But as Shadow Wizard mentions in the comments above, IE might not like treating 'article' as a real DOM element.

Comment: As @mmcnickle points out correctly. Every version of IE below IE9 doesnt understand article as a DOM, changed it into a div and now it works fine!

thnx for the respons :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the IE is making cache of your code.

See this post: [jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Add .each(function(){...}); after .load , it should works in IE and Chrome.

```
        $('#<%=image1.ClientID %>').load(function () {
            //things to do
        }).each(function () {
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
```