# jQuerys .load() function on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am using the `.load()` function like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $("#id").load('file.php');
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#id").load('file.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly in FF and Chrome. It also works perfectly in IE7.

BUT:

It displays an error message in the bottom bar of IE7 which says:

> The object does not support this property or method.

I guess this is because IE7 doesn't support the `.load()` function.

Is there any way to get rid of this message? It looks really ugly and I'm not sure my boss will approve.

EDIT:

I found the reason!

It was because I used the online version of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

It works fine if I switch to a local copy of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error usually specifies which method it is referring to - is it not telling you in the console, or even giving you a line number? The `.load()` function works fine in IE7 so my guess is that there is some code elsewhere causing the issue.

Comment: Apparently it is my jquery include line. I am now trying out old jquery versions to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason!

It was because I used the online version of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

It works fine if I switch to a local copy of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe check if your function is a function.

```
if(typeof $("#id").load == 'function')
```

or replace it with a $.get

```
$.get("file.php", function (data) {
```

like the following post [jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)