# My jQuery code not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The below code rocks in Chrome and FF but not working in IE I checked for similar questions in SO. Some didn't help me and some I couldn't understand as I am a newbie to jQuery. Please help me in fixing this error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
       $('#container').load('mypage.aspx #div1');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does taking out the space help? How about taking out the nested `$(document).ready`s?

Comment: @minitech - I didn't understand what you are saying. Can you please post a guess answer?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening the IE Developer toolbar and watching the network trace.  Is the request to mypage.aspx coming back?  Or does it return a 500 server error response code?  Does it even fire the request at all?

Another option, try changing you code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#container').load('mypage.aspx #div1');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, press F12 to get to that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes a difference specifically for IE, but you are double-declaring the function scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#container').load('mypage.aspx #div1');
});
</script>
```

You may try and see if this works.