# why .load is not refreshing php file on IE?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

am using .load to refresh one div after inserting data or deleting data. it is working fine on chrome, mozilla. but the problem is with IE. After changing data it was loading file, but not refreshing

here is code sample

```
function updatedinformation(sid)
 {

    $("#load").load("load.php?sid="+sid).fadeIn("slow");

 }
```

how i can solve this?

Comment: load does not get fired in IE8 for files that are already in the browser cache

Comment: [jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061525/1693859)