# IE 10 wont reload my directory proper after uploading file with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post, internet-explorer-10

I am having some headaching trouble with IE 10. (who doesn't)

I have this upload function, where a user can upload certain files (PDF's) to the admin part of a website.

After the upload is completed I use jQuery to show the contents of the dir through a jQuery.post action, in effect reloading the dir contents and printing them to the screen.

I all other browsers (tested Opera, Chrome, Firefox) everything works out fine. But in IE10 the contents of the directory printed to the screen seems to be a cached version. By using an FTP program I can verify that the file is actually uploaded with IE10, but it won't read the updated contents. I have to restart the IE10 browser in order for it to reload proper.

Any ideas on how to force IE10 to read contents from scratch or maybe another solution?

### Code for reload

```
<table>
<?php
$dir_handle = opendir("../../images/certificates");
while (($entry = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false){
  // Only show PDF's
  $filetest = preg_match('/(.pdf|.PDF)$/',$entry);
  if ($filetest){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td rel='{$entry}'><img class='pdfdownloadicon imageIcon' src='images/pdfdownload.png' />{$entry}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
$typeOfFileShow = "document";
?>
```

### Script that executes above code

```
function showFileBrowser(path) {
  currentTypeOfFileShow = path;
  $("#fileselectbox").load("includes/filebrowser."+path+".inc.php");
  $("#filebrowser").slideDown('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> through a jQuery.post action

[`.load('...')`](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.load) uses a `GET` request unless you give it an object as the second parameter.

Use an empty object as the second parameter to send an uncached `POST` request

```
$("#fileselectbox").load("includes/filebrowser."+path+".inc.php", {});
```

Or set `cache: false` as the default setting with

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Hey Andreas. (and you other 2 :) Thanks alot for a quick solution. I didn't see that little mistake and it solved my issue. EDIT: I didn't try the random number / time thing, 'cause other parts of the code on this particular page, requires the GET string to be empty. But thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a rand number to cheat Internet Explorer cache?

For example

```
function showFileBrowser(path) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    currentTypeOfFileShow = path;
    $("#fileselectbox").load("includes/filebrowser."+path+".inc.php&r="+randomnumber);
    $("#filebrowser").slideDown('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari), with the time in your request, IE may not caching.

```
$("#fileselectbox").load("includes/filebrowser."+path+".inc.php" + new Date().getTime() );
```