# Ajax embed page load not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to load an html page located on my server into a div frame (iframe won't scroll properly using a custom scrollbar) and it loads fine in firefox but not anything else it seems (tho it was working in IE at one point I am pretty sure).

```
<div id="scroll" class="news frame" style="position:absolute;width:570px;height:430px;margin:0px auto;left:143px;top:70px;background:#fff;overflow:auto;overflow-y: hidden;">
<div id="load"></div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').load('http://www.bizzaromatic.com/news.html');
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Obviously I need some sort of cross-browser solution but my limited knowledge of JS and Jquery has led me to here.

Edit: If someone has a better method to embed a page in a frame that isn't iframes I will gladly listen to that as well.

Comment: JS/jQuery can't dot that. you need server-side code to get that URL and pass it to your JS

Comment: maybe a cross domain issue. see the conlsole window by pressing f12 key in most browser

Comment: In Chrome I get this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bizzaromatic.com/news.html. Origin http://bizzaromatic.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: It's working in everything but IE right now. It was seeing my own website as a cross domain for some reason. However I am no longer getting the above error in Chrome or IE so...

Answer (score 0):

There are topics with several solutions to this issue, check this topic: [jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)

One of the answers (adapted to your code):

```
<div id="scroll" class="news frame" style="position:absolute;width:570px;height:430px;margin:0px auto;left:143px;top:70px;background:#fff;overflow:auto;overflow-y: hidden;">
  <div id="load"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery.get("http://www.bizzaromatic.com/news.html", function (data) { 
          data = '"' + data + '"';    
          $("#load").html(data);
          var newHTML = $('#load').html();
          $('#load').html(newHTML.substr(1,newHTML.length-2));
      });
  });
  </script>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not working except in FF.

As per a suggestion above I checked the dev console in Chrome and get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load bizzaromatic.com/news.html. Origin bizzaromatic.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". I tried to fix it via .htaccess but no luck so far.

Comment: Ok so now it works in chrome adding "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://bizzaromatic.com" but not in IE as of yet.

Comment: I'm wondering if the origin (where you're using this frame) is the same as the one you're pulling the HTML file. To avoid cross-domain issues both elements must be on the same bizzaromatic.com domain. If not, then you could try something like this: [Cross-Domain requests with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dotnet Dreamer for the hint/reminder about browser console stuff. That was a launchpad to get this working.

I put:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://bizzaromatic.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

in my .htaccess and it all seems fine now. Thanks to everyone else as well for taking time out of your day to help.