# load method not firing

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
 $('#song').css('color','green');
 $('#song').load('getSong.py');
```

I have the first statement to verify that jQuery is working properly.  It is.  The <div id='song' style='color:darkblue'> turns green.  But the url getSong.py is not called.  I have Fiddler2 turned on and no web url is called.

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: check console for errors ?

Comment: No errors. Console just said: HTML1300: Navigation occurred.

Comment: Oh, I just discovered that it works fine in Chrome and my Android phone browser.  I was testing using IE 11 on Windows 8.1 and that is the one not working.  Are there any special settings required on IE11?

Comment: Read [This](http://zacster.blogspot.in/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/)

Comment: Thanks.  It was a caching problem.  Solved by adding a timestamp to the url.

Comment: append current datetime to url