# All html a-tags not not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Website is working very well in other browsers: FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, safari ios. However, When i go to my home page in ie11, none of my links work including those in the nav menu. When a user clicks on the link it just refreshes the page. If you try to put a new url in the address bar, manually even it doesn't allow you to leave the page.

http://nosacares.org

How can I fix this so the hyperlinks work?

Some specifics:

This is a site built mostly using bootstrap 3.5

Here are a few different examples of links that are not working:

```
<a href="people/join_volunteers.php" class="btn btn-ghost btn-primary btn-lg text-theme"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Volunteer</a> 

<div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
  <div class="list-inline social-icons-menu-top pull-right"> 
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nosacares" class="social-hover-v1 a-facebook"></a>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=key" class="social-hover-v1 a-youtube"></a> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <li> <a href="http://mywebsite.org/community/press_archives.php">Press Archives</a> </li>
```

When I run the dev tools, and test these links a couple different errors come up that seem like they could be relevant:

DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.
HTML1300: Navigation occurred. (this one will pop up a few times for each click)

I would have figured this would be a very common problem but my searching has not found anything that has worked yet, nor anyone that has had an entire site break in ie like this.

I'm up for any suggestions here, including what the best way to test this in the dev tools would be?

Comment: You have the wrong URL entered for the bootstrap css. You included an underscore between bootstrap and .min. `http://nosacares.org/css/bootstrap.min.css` is the proper link.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that i fixed it, but problem still exist. please look again if you can. nosacares.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are fine, so it isn't that.

This issue seems to be related to corrupt entries in the compatibility view list within Internet Explorer 11.
The temporary Internet files in Internet Explorer 11, sometimes called the cache, are the copies of text, images, and other data from recently viewed websites that are stored on your hard drive.

Refer this Microsoft article to clear the cache in Internet Explorer 11:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/internet-explorer/manage-delete-browsing-history-internet-explorer#ie=ie-11

In addition to that, please delete the iecompatdata.xml file from the following location:
C:\Users\aName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml

Source: [Microsoft site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/dom-console-keeps-popping-up-when-simply-browsing/d55bd727-0703-47cf-8de6-876b0b33cfdd)

But it could also be a problem with jQuery, take a look at this and see if it could help you out:
[jQuery's .load() not working in IE - but fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061525/jquerys-load-not-working-in-ie-but-fine-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: I've tested it on multiple computers, including one running edge in newest windows OS. I'm checking on jquery issue, could on to something there.

Comment: <script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
</script> THIS IS THE CULPRIT

Comment: So I guess it's fixed, great! :)